# Dynamic Script Block - Java Runtime Error - Webforms

Tags: webforms

I have an old WebForms app that I'm working on.  I'm running in debug mode.

I get an error message when loading a page.  It is a message from a dynamic script:

Javascript Runtime Error "False" is undefined

I'm stuck as to how to debug this.  I was thinking that I might need to update a nuget package, but I don't know which one.

**Update:**

Get this error with IE 11.  Do not get the error with Chrome.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting the error both places? Perhaps search the page source (from browser) for "False" and figure out where that is coming from.

Comment: The "False" was not in the page source, however I did poke around after hitting debug in VS and figured out that my Password Manager (LastPass) was causing the error.  Turned off the password manager and we are in business.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Ok... so the error is in your Password Manager, not your code?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure they have an error in their code, but their toolbar/password manager does NOT get along with VS in debug mode... It cases errors in the dynamic JS that VS builds.   I don't claim to understand why totally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else hits this.  I was using LastPass password manager.  For some reason the JavaScript did not behave when using Visual Studio debugging with IE.  I turned the password manager (LastPass) off and we were home free.